# Where should I populate a required hidden field post-submission in a Django Form?

Tags: django, forms, validation, django-forms

I thought it would be in the `form` `clean` method, but I get a `required` error, so I must be wrong.

I'm using a `ModelForm`, hiding one of the fields with `form.fields['field_name'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()`, and trying to fill it in after submission based on other data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to fill in the value, then you shouldn't include the field in your form at all. You could use [`exclude`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use) to do this:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ('field_name',)
```

Then in your view, call [`save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) with `commit=False`, and set the value before saving again.

```
if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.field_name = get_field_value()
    instance.save()
```

Comment: I think I dumbed out for a bit - thanks. Where would get_field_value() go, given it's needed wherever the form is used? In forms.py?

Comment: It's up to you where it goes, but `forms.py` sounds ok. If you're reusing the form in lots of places, then you might want to override the form's `save()` method and set the value there.

Comment: Perfect, I'll put it in the save(). Any thoughts on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32497711/

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing this via a field at all? If it's not visible to the user and not populated by anything that they do, it shouldn't be in the form. Exclude it from the modelform altogether, and set it in the view when you save:

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save()
    obj.field_name = my_value
    obj.save()
```